# Problem setting custom bash prompt showng git branch

Tags: bash

This is my configuration in Macbook bash profile

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

I copied this configuration from [David Walsh's website](https://davidwalsh.name/show-git-branch-command-line).

When I execute the command

```
myuser@Users-Macbook myproject % pwd
/Users/myuser/projects/myproject

usere@Users-Macbook myproject % source ~/.bash_profile
```

I see that the exact content of exported variable`PS1` is written as a string as given below i.e. the string is not evaluated.

```
\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ pwd

/Users/myuser/projects/myproject

\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $
```

I don't know what it is that I am doing wrong. It was working before, and now I don't know what happened. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bash? What's the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: The output is `-zsh`

Comment: So, you're trying to use a Bash style prompt, but you're using Zshell.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Use Bash instead of Zsh, or use a prompt in Zsh format.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

`\` is used for escaping character. `\$` means a literal dollar sign.

example:

```
$my_func()  { echo "I am function"; }
$export var1="abc \$(my_func) 123"
$echo $var1
abc $(my_func) 123
$export var1="abc $(my_func) 123"
$echo $var1
abc I am function 123
$
```

Comment: `PS1` is evaluated for every prompt; your suggestion would result in `$(parse_git_branch)` being evaluated only once (on assignment) instead of for every prompt. The common solution is to *single quote* `PS1` when defining it, or just escape `\$`, not the other way around.